# Changing position of children of layout

Tags: c#, xaml

When my timer goes below 10 seconds , I want to change its position.It is declared in xaml as a child of a Relative Layout:

```
<local:Timer 
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width , Factor=0.48}"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent , Property=Height , Factor=0.45}"/>
```

Timer is just a view which contains a label which is bound to a property in code-behind.I don't know how to get access to its position in c# and then change it...Help?

Answer (score 0):

One creates a [storyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/storyboards-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) animator to change differing properties of controls on such a situation. When the timer goes off, run the storyboard which will change the values you preset on the storyboard for the control(s); hence changing the location.

Comment: I've never heard of it...I'll look into it, thanks.